# Defining a new parameterized Exception type

Tags: exception, haskell

I need to throw an exception that contains some polymorphic type thing `a` for the handler to deal with, like

```
data MyException a = MyException a
    deriving (Typeable)
```

Where I initially had an `Exception` instance:

```
instance Show (MyException a) where
    show _ = "MyException"
instance Exception (MyException a)
```

However this is a type error with

```
No instance for (Typeable a)
  arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
In the instance declaration for
  ‘Exception (MyException a)’
```

Do I need to make the `a` a `Dynamic`? That seems wrong since we're already doing that sort of coercion stuff in the handler. What's the idiomatic way to do this?

I'm on GHC 7.8

Comment: The definition of `Exception` is now `class (Typeable e, Show e) => Exception e`. `MyException a` is only an instance of `Typeable` if `a` is. So you need to write `instance Typeable a => Exception (MyException a)`.

Comment: Sorry, this question was too hasty. The real issue is I don't want to have that `Typeable` constraint on `a`. And of course I would need that if I were using `Dynamic` too. Hmmm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tested, but it's probably enough to amend your code this way:

```
instance Typeable a => Exception (MyException a)
```

(In fact, what you really demand is

```
instance Typeable (MyException a) => Exception (MyException a)
```

but because of the `deriving` clause, you know you have the instance demanded in the context whenever you have `Typeable a`.)